# Excel VBA for loop causes 100% CPU

Tags: excel, vba

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim r As Range
Dim a As Long


Set op = Worksheets("ZVCTOSTATUS")
Set CP = op.Columns("J")
Set CTO = op.Range("J1")
Set OD = op.Columns("G")
Set ZV = op.Columns("H")

op.Activate
fa = op.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set r = op.Range("J2:J" & fa)

For Each C In r
   CTO = CP.Cells(C.Row, 1).Value
    If CTO = "FG BOOKED" Or CTO = "CLOSED" Then
       ZV.Cells(C.Row, 1) = 0
    ElseIf CTO = "NOT STARTED" Or CTO = "UNCONFIRMED" Then
        ZV.Cells(C.Row, 1) = OD.Cells(C.Row, 1).Value
End If
Next C
```

I am using this code to go through my worksheet making a For loop to change value in Column H by referencing to Column J.

When this code is used on a standalone worksheet, it seems to work perfectly. But once I port it over to a much bigger file which has data connection, and I run this macro only individually, it causes my CPU to run at 100% and takes up to 10 minutes.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: How many cores does your machine have? VBA runs in a single threaded apartment.

Comment: Is `CTO` an object?  If so, what type?  You are doing a `Set CTO = op.Range("J1")` as well as a `CTO = CP.Cells(C.Row, 1).Value` which seems .... strange.

Comment: CPU Spec: Intel Core i5-6300U @ 2.40 Ghz
RAM 8GB

Comment: @YowE3K 
I still relatively new to excel VBA but this coding seems to do what it is intended, feel free to re-code it if there is a much better way

Comment: First thing I would try is to disable them all: EnableEvents=false: ScreenUpdating=false and especially Calculation=xlManual...

Comment: @YowE3K it's likely a variant otherwise it would error. My assumption on this is there's probably a huge amount of transactions going on, so many adjustments to cell values. Evan consider loading the data into an array and doing the edit operations there instead, then pasting the array back to the sheet.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks for the tip, i put the Calculation=xlManual before the For Loop and Calculation=xlAutomatic just after now the code runs 100x faster
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help your macro run smoother you can insert the below code before your main code (just below the sub) and right after your code (just before the end sub)
This will turn off screen updates, alerts, and set the calculation to manual so no formulas are updating until after the process has ran.

```
   'Please Before Main Code'
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Application.Calculation = xlManual

  'Insert main code here'

  'Place After Main code'
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you fell in a trap which has the following features:

1. You are using a large excel file which is several MB in size
2. The excel document is full of formula and data connection
3. Additionally it might have pivot tables and charts
4. Calculation option for Formula is Automatic

Try this:
1. Go to formula tab
2. Click "Calculation Option"
3. Select "Manual"

[image: Screenshot for your reference]

Now execute the macro you have created. It should be good to go. Once the macro is executed. You can change the calculation option.

Note: You can control the calculation option problematically as well using below snippet:

```
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    ' This will set the calculation mode to manual
    With Application
      CalcMode = .Calculation
      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .EnableEvents = False
    End With

     << Add your macro processing here >>

    ' Again switch back to the original calculation option
    With Application
       .ScreenUpdating = True
       .EnableEvents = True
       .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
```

Excel tries to calculate the values (based on formula) everytime any cell is changed. This is done for the entire document for every cell updated by your macro. So, for large excel document, it causes high CPU consumption.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting values of cells one at a time triggering a recalculation. The way to do this correctly is to read the columns into memory first, set the values and write the results *with one operation*.

```
Public Sub AnswerPost()

    Dim r_status As Range, r_value As Range, r_calc As Range
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim op As Worksheet

    Set op = Worksheets("ZVCTOSTATUS")
    ' Find the number of items on cell "J2" and below
    n = Range(op.Range("J2"), op.Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    ' Set the n×1 range of cells under "J", "G" and "H" columns
    Set r_status = op.Range("J2").Resize(n, 1)
    Set r_value = op.Range("G2").Resize(n, 1)
    Set r_calc = op.Range("H2").Resize(n, 1)

    Dim x_status() As Variant, x_value() As Variant, x_calc() As Variant
    ' Read cells from the worksheet into memory arrays
    x_status = r_status.Value2
    x_value = r_value.Value2
    x_calc = r_status.Value2
    ' Set values of x_calc based on x_status, row by row.
    For i = 1 To n
        Select Case x_status(i, 1)
            Case "FG BOOKED", "CLOSED"
                x_calc(i, 1) = 0#
            Case "NOT STARTED", "UNCONFIRMED"
                x_calc(i, 1) = x_value(i, 1)
        End Select
    Next i
    ' Write the resulting array back into the worksheet
    r_calc.Value2 = x_calc
End Sub
```

Test case for above code

[image: screen]

Comment: What does Resizee (n,1) do ?

Comment: For example `Range("A1").Resize(10,3)` is equivalent to `Range("A1:C10")`. So it resizes the range of cells with a numeric values for the #rows and #columns. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274.aspx)

Comment: @EvanGoh you see using `Cells()` refers to the entire worksheet, but with `Range(ref).Resize(nx,ny)` you get the table of values with `ref` as top left, and `(nx,ny)` as row and column count. If things move around in the worksheet it is a pain to retarget all the `Cells()`, but if you use named ranges (like `Range("data_table")`) you don't have to do anything.